# JQuery Feature Detection for <a href="data:..."> support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html2canvas

I have am using html2canvas to enable screenshots of divs within my web application. It's working well enough in Chrome (including Android), Safari (including iOS) and FireFox. In IE 11, however the image won't save.

Code looks like this:

```
function displayModalWithImage(canvas, filename) {

    var modalcontainer = $('#snapshot');
    var modalcontainer_body = modalcontainer.children().find('.snap_shot_container');
    var modalcontainer_save = modalcontainer.children().find('.save_snapshot');

    var image = new Image();
    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    image.src = data;

    modalcontainer_save.attr('download', filename +".png");
    modalcontainer_save.attr('href', 
        data.replace(/^data[:]image\/png[;]/i, "data:application/octet-stream;"));
    $(modalcontainer_body).html('');
    $(image).appendTo(modalcontainer_body);
    $(modalcontainer_save).on('click', function() {
        modalcontainer.modal('hide');
    });

    modalcontainer.modal();
}
```

Browser behavior varies:

1. Chrome: displays modal and then saves the file when "Save" is clicked. (acceptable)
2. Firefox: displays modal and then displays a separate dialog when "Save" is clicked (acceptable)
3. Safari: display modal and then loads image in a separate tab when "Save" is clicked (acceptable... maybe)
4. IE 11: displays modal, but does nothing but hide the dialog when "Save" is clicked (unacceptable)

The `data.replace` was suggested by another SO answer, but it did not appear to have any effect on the behavior of any of the browsers.  Previously the href attribute was simply set to data.

So, anyway, at this point replacing the modal dialog with a simple `window.location = data` is a viable alternative.  But, since Chrome works well and Safari and FF work well enough, i'd like to simply do a feature detection that would `window.location` for IE but show the modal for the other browsers.  But, I don't know what "feature" is missing in IE to check for.

**tl;dr**

1. is there simply a change or bug in my javascript that would enable IE to work (save the image encoded as data to a file).
2. if not, which feature in IE should I detect for that would enable me to customize the behavior for IE
3. if that's not an option; what's the current best practices for old-fashioned browser detection?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A quick read and I don't think that's the solution. In the referenced question, `canvas.toDataURL()` throws the error but that is working in IE to display the image (it's the href on the `<a>` tag that is not). And there's no SVG in the page being rendered. It's all HTML or canvas.

Comment: you can't use this feature with IE11, you should try to use something other than an anchor tag `<a>` to get the image to the user http://caniuse.com/#feat=download